# Using Spring.net.Social only

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, linkedin-api, spring.net

Our app uses Prism/MEF and now we need to tie into twitter/facebook/linkedin/google+ etc.

The Spring.Net social library seems to wrap a few of those so question is -

Is it possible to use *only* spring.social from a wpf app ?

Or alternatively, any other library which wraps a few of the social api's ?

One other library we found is socialauth.net but that's primarily for use in web apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, you don't need to use spring.net dependency injection framework to use spring.social; it only has a dependency on spring.rest (which in turn has no dependencies). So you should be able to use it with Prism/MEF or whatever framework you use.

Check out the [nuget packages](http://nuget.org/packages?q=spring.social) - it appears that atm Twitter, LinkedIn and Dropbox are supported, so not all your requirements are met.

It appears that a facebook lpugin [is under development at the moment](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-facebook).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Spring.NET Social alone as shown in the sample.